# The shell command "top" shows which processes from the /proc directory?

Tags: top

The manual page states,

> The  top  program  provides  a dynamic real-time view of a running
>   system.  It can display system summary information as  well  as  a
>   list  of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux 
>   kernel.  The types of system summary  information  shown  and  the
>   types,  order  and size of information displayed for processes are all
>   user configurable and that configuration can be  made  persistent
>   across restarts.

When running this command, it shows some processes having `pid`'s ranging from 1 onwards. And some other processes refreshing after some time interval. What kind of those particular processes are? On what criteria top shows these `threads` or `processes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `top` shows the processes with the highest amount of cpu percentage ascending. This percentage is calculated from the last time `top` has refreshed. Normally this interval is 3 seconds. `top` is an interactive and highly configurable command.

This interval as well as the sort order (and 1000 other things) can be changed, if you want so:

- Press <kbd>d</kbd> to change the interval, type `0.1` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you will see the faster interval.
- Press <kbd>F</kbd> to change the sort order, then type <kbd>n</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, the output is ordered by memory usage.
- Press <kbd>f</kbd> to toggle fields. Then press <kbd>r</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will now see a new field called `CODE`.
- Press <kbd>r</kbd> to renice a process.

That's just a few examples.